# jQuery how to target the data in these sibling td's?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, siblings, parents

So when `modalLink` is clicked I want to grab and save the data values from the other `td`'s inside of this `tr` and not other `tr`'s

```
<tr date-user-id="1NJD3A" data-user-details="{...}" class="">
    <td class="table-request-btn incoming-icon">
        <button class="modalLink" href="#modalrequest">Request Intro</button>
    </td>
    <td class="data-name request-row">
        Joe Blow
    </td>
    <td class="data-career request-row">
        Administrator
    </td>
    <td class="data-company request-row">
        Acme
    </td>
</tr>
```

My function so far which is throwing an unreable Uncaught TypeError

How would you approach this problem?

```
var wireSearchTable = function() {
    $('.modalLink').unbind('click').bind('click', function () {
        var request_name = $(this).parents('tr').siblings.data('name');
        var request_title = $(this).siblings.data('career');
        var request_company = $(this).siblings.data('company');
            requestIntroModal.wireRequestIntroModal(details);

            console.log('request_name = '+request_name);
            console.log('request_title = '+request_title);
            console.log('request_company = '+request_company);
        });
    };
```

Comment: And can you show a sample of the resulting HTML (instead of the templating you're using to *create* that HTML)?

Comment: Why are you using siblings instead of siblings()? Besides, href isn't a valid property for a button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd personally suggest:

```
$('button.modalLink').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');

    // I have absolutely no idea what the following is meant to do,
    // if anything, therefore it's not in the linked demo,
    // and remains commented-out here.
    // requestIntroModal.wireRequestIntroModal(details);

    people = {
        'name': row.find('td.data-name').text(),
            'career': row.find('td.data-career').text(),
            'company': row.find('td.data-company').text()
    };
    console.log(people);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ZJz2N/).

References:

- [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have been of help! =)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you want?

```
var wireSearchTable = function() {
    $('.modalLink').unbind('click').bind('click', function () {
        var this_tr = $(this).closest('tr'),  // grab the parent <tr>
            request_name = this_tr.siblings('.some-class-name-or-id').data('name'),
            request_title = this_tr.find('.data-career').data('career'),
            request_company = this_tr.find('.data-company').data('company');

        requestIntroModal.wireRequestIntroModal(details);

        console.log('request_name = '+request_name);
        console.log('request_title = '+request_title);
        console.log('request_company = '+request_company);
    });
};
```